# Compile Git to use OpenSSL library libssl.so.1.0.1

Tags: compiling, git, suse, linker

Running a system that only has full support for OpenSSL version 0.9.8.

Installed in parallel is OpenSSL 1.0.1 libraries (Supported by Distro)

Git still preferentially uses the 0.9.8 libraries but we need it to use 1.0.1.

Can Git be built from source to use libssl.so.1.0.0 libraries so we can interact with https://github.com using TLS v1.2 ?

For E.g:

`/usr/lib64/git/git-http-fetch ->        libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00007ffff6c78000)
/usr/lib64/git/git-http-push ->         libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00007ffff6a4d000)
/usr/lib64/git/git-imap-send ->         libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00007ffff7d56000)
/usr/lib64/git/git-remote-ftp ->        libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00007ffff6a4d000)
/usr/lib64/git/git-remote-ftps ->       libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00007ffff6a4d000)
/usr/lib64/git/git-remote-http ->       libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00007ffff6a4d000)
/usr/lib64/git/git-remote-https ->      libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00007ffff6a4d000)`

Need to link to `libssl.so.1.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work (for testing purposes)
With thanks to  
[Shawna Jean](https://gist.github.com/seveas/6a00d20aa40f9ca677c96eb44a6c5140)

Building Git against the libraries we wanted.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/git-test-inst/lib
mkdir git-test-inst

cd git-test-inst/
wget https://dl.uxnr.de/mirror/curl/curl-7.59.0.tar.gz
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0h.tar.gz
wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.16.3.tar.gz
mv v2.16.3 git-2.16.3.tar.gz

tar -xf openssl-1.1.0h.tar.gz 
cd openssl-1.1.0h
./config --prefix=/home/$USER/git-test-inst
make -j16
make -j16 install
cd ../

tar xf curl-7.59.0.tar.gz 
cd curl-7.59.0
./configure --with-ssl=/home/$USER/git-test-inst/ --prefix=/home/$USER/git-test-inst/
make -j16
make install
ldd /home/$USER/git-test-inst/lib/libcurl.so.4.5.0 
cd ..

tar xf git-2.16.3.tar.gz 
cd git-2.16.3
make configure
./configure --prefix=/home/$USER/git-test-inst/ --with-openssl=/home/$USER/git-test-inst/ --with-curl=/home/$USER/git-test-inst/
make -j16
make install
ldd /home/$USER/git-test-inst/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https
```

And the tested against repos Github.com

Answer (score 0):

This works for me! `git` just depends on `curl`, thanks.

1. compile the latest `openssl` and install
2. compile the `curl` and install
3. compile the `git` and install