# Old CentOS 5.6, Due to github.com delete the TLSv1/TLSv1.1 support, How can I access to github.com/repo.git using git system

Tags: linux, centos, git, openssl, github

Now I have a cluster with Rocks 5.4 based on CentOS 5.6. When I `git push` the code to *github.com*, I run into the errors:

> error: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version while accessing http://github.com/

related link:
[Compile Git to use OpenSSL library libssl.so.1.0.1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438504/compile-git-to-use-openssl-library-libssl-so-1-0-1/444718#444718)
https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

Hope someone give a solution. Thank you very much!
Qiang

Comment: Two options, either upgrading to a more recent CentOS, or setting up a frontend service/Server that talks a more recent version of TLS.

Comment: CentOS 5 is well past its end of life; I would think long and hard about whether you want to continue using unsupported infrastructure as opposed to running something current wherein you will not be encountering this sort of issue.

Comment: Because It is the old cluster, upgrading more recent CentOS may bring more pains, So that is not my options. About another solution may give some details?

Comment: CentOS 5 is dead. You are only going to continue to encounter situations like this, rendering your cluster useless. Spend your energy building a new cluster with a supported OS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of people still running RHEL 5 / CentOS 5 for several reasons. Unfortunately RHEL 5 is out of support and additionally there was never a package with OpenSSL >= 1 for RHEL 5.

If you don't have any concerns about using a foreign repo then you can use "tuxad repo". It provides a different and more easy way **to update OpenSSL of RHEL 5 to the one of RHEL 6** (which is still supported):

1. Install tuxad repo for RHEL 5: rpm -i http://www.tuxad.de/repo/5/tuxad.rpm
2. Update packages: yum update

More details can be found here:

[www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2014/11/19/openssl_updatesenhancements_for_rhel__centos_5](http://www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2014/11/19/openssl_updatesenhancements_for_rhel__centos_5/index.html)
[www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2018/07/21/tuxad_rh5_repo_now_with_phpopenssl1](http://www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2018/07/21/tuxad_rh5_repo_now_with_phpopenssl1/index.html)

This repo contains several packages which are rebuild against OpenSSL 1:

- httpd (also include other enhancements like ECDH support)
- postfix
- dovecot
- curl
- lynx
- mutt
- vsftpd
- w3m
- wget
- php
- php from RHEL 6 backported (in separate repo "tuxad-php")